# Why isn't this program running properly?

Tags: java, stack

The assignment was to create a postfix to infix converter using Stacks. The program compiles properly but when I tried to make a demo class, I received a null point exception line 32. Please share any observations, better coding conventions, or solutions.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class PostfixtoInfix {
    private String expression;
    private Stack<Character> s;
    Character pOpen = new Character('(');
    Character pClose = new Character(')');

    public String PostfixtoInfix(String e) {
        expression = e;
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < e.length(); i++) {
            char currentChar = e.charAt(i);
            if (isOperator(currentChar)) {
                while (!s.empty() && s.peek() != pOpen
                        && hasHigherPrecedence(s.peek(), currentChar)) {
                    output += s.peek();
                    s.pop();
                }
                s.push(currentChar);
            } else if (isOperand(currentChar)) {
                output += currentChar;
            } else if (currentChar == '(') {
                s.push(currentChar);
            } else if (currentChar == ')') {
                while (!s.empty() && s.peek() != pClose) {
                    output += s.peek();
                    s.pop();
                }
            }
            while (!s.empty()) {
                output += s.peek();
                s.pop();
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    public boolean isOperator(char c) {
        if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '/' || c == '*' || c == '^')
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isOperand(char c) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            return true;
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            return true;
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int getOperatorWeight(char operator) {
        int weight = -1;
        switch (operator) {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            weight = 1;
            break;

        case '*':
        case '/':
            weight = 2;
            break;

        case '^':
            weight = 3;
        }
        return weight;
    }

    public boolean hasHigherPrecedence(char operator1, char operator2) {
        int op1 = getOperatorWeight(operator1);
        int op2 = getOperatorWeight(operator2);
        if (op1 == op2) {
            if (isRightAssociative(operator1))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        return op1 > op2 ? true : false;
    }

    public boolean isRightAssociative(char op) {
        if (op == '^')
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Advice? Learn to use your debugger and google.

Comment: I voted to close because "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Answer (score 2):

To fix the NPE **initialize your objects**. Unlike C++, `Stack<Character> s;` is equivalent to `Stack<Character> s = null;`; *not* to `Stack<Character> s = new Stack<>();`!

Beware of `==` and `!=` *not* behaving as you might expect for **boxed** objects.

```
Character a = new Character('A');
Character aa = new Character('A');
System.out.println(a == aa);
```

gives the (correct!) answer `false`.

They are *different objects*. If you want to compare for equality, use either:

```
System.out.println(a.equals(aa));
System.out.println((char)a==(char)aa);
```

The first uses an explicit method for comparing the *object contents*. The second one avoids this problem by using non-object primitives, where equality is bitwise, not reference-equality.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you declare a private member `s`, never assign anything to it, and then attempt to use it in expressions like `s.empty()` and `s.pop()`.  If nothing is ever assigned to `s`, then it is `null`, and attempting to call a method on it will result in a NullPointerException.

To create an empty stack, you probably want to change the declaration to:

```
private Stack <Character> s = new Stack<Character>();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a method looking like a constructor:

```
public String PostfixtoInfix(String e) {
```

try changing it to something else, like:

```
public String transform(String e) {
```

Second, your `s` field never gets assigned a stack. Put

```
s = new Stack<Character>();
```

in your constructor. Also, `new Character('a') != new Character('a')`, because that will bypass automatic (pillowweight cached) boxing. Use instead just simple `char`s as pOpen and pClose.

Answer (score -2):

Your access modifier may be preventing the program to access the stack. 
Change:

```
private Stack <Character> s;
```

to:

```
protected Stack <Character> s;
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Comment: Don't know of any way that would cause a NullPointerException.  Should cause a compiler error if anything.